# Why am I getting an infinite loop when I don't define the parameters?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I would like to know why I am getting an infinite loop here. I just don't want to pass this initial values, so if they are `undefined` they get automatically calculated. Its just to clean my function call to use only a single parameter. If I pass them everything runs ok and the process ends. Can anyone help? Thanks

```
function merge(array, lower, half, upper){
    //Suppressed for the sake of brevity
}

function mergeSort(array, lower, upper){
    if(!lower && !upper){ //take a look here
        lower = 0;
        upper = array.length - 1;
    }

    if(lower < upper){
        var half = Math.floor((lower + upper)/2);

        mergeSort(array, lower, half);
        mergeSort(array, half + 1, upper);
        merge(array, lower, half, upper);
    }
}

var array = [8, 3, 6, 4, 1, 0, 23, 12, 15, 63];
mergeSort(array); //infinite loop here
console.log(array);
```

Comment: Thanks for fixing your variable names. :) You want `if(lower == undefined && upper == undefined)` instead of `if(!lower && !upper)`.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville take a look at how my Merge function is now looking like; https://gist.github.com/3165423 - you can leave comments at the gist page for improvements!!! Thanks for the positive criticism! =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your very first recursive call to `mergeSort` passed it `0` as first argument, because you set it so.

since `!0` also evalutes to `false`, here you go..

Better check against `undefined` by using the `typeof` operator

```
if(typeof lower === 'undefined' && typeof upper === 'undefined'){ //take a look here
    lower = 0;
    upper = array.length - 1;
}
```

or, even better, check the `arguments.length`, like

```
if( arguments.length === 1 ) {
   var lower = 0,
       upper = array.length -1 ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @jAndy, the type coersion that the operator ==/!= performs has just caught me this time...  What do you think of `if(lower == undefined && upper == undefined)` and/or `if(lower === undefined && upper === undefined)`?

Comment: @RenatoGama: that is just fine aswell if your arguments are always declared. By checking `arguments.length` you don't even need to have that requirement. But that is totally a question of taste :-)